# Executing Oracle function with CLOB data using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, spring, clob, spring-jdbc

I have oracle table like,

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST(
INFO1 VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR),
INFO2 VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR),
INFO CLOB)
```

For inserting data into this table I have one function which returns empty clob

```
function Insert_TEST(in_infotext1 in T_TEST.info1%type := null,
                     in_infotext2 in T_TEST.info2%type := null,)
    return T_TEST.info%type
is
    l_info T_TEST.info%type;
begin
    insert into T_TEST
            ( INFO1,
              INFO2,
              info,)
     values ( in_infotext1,
              in_infotext2,
              empty_clob())
     returning info into l_info;
     return l_info;
  end;
```

To call this function I'm using following sql,

```
declare
    myinfo clob;
begin
    myinfo := Insert_TEST('Info1', 'Info2');
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(myinfo, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE(myinfo,14,1,'My Information');
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(myinfo);
    COMMIT;
end;
```

This sql working perfectly from SQL Developer, But when I try to execute this sql using org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate my program goes into infinite looop.
My Java coding is as below

```
OracleConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
        dataSource.setUser("test");
        dataSource.setPassword("test");

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        String query =

                "declare "+
                "  myinfo clob;                                                           "+
                "begin                                                                    "+
                "    myinfo := Insert_TEST('Info1', 'Info2');"+
                "    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(myinfo, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);                       "+
                "    DBMS_LOB.WRITE(myinfo,14,1,'My Information');                        "+
                "    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(myinfo);                                              "+
                "    COMMIT;                                                              "+
                "end;";

        jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
```

Thanks

Comment: "infinite loop"?  What makes you think that?  I sincerely doubt it; it's far more likely that you have an empty catch block that swallows the exception telling you what you've done wrong.  There are Spring classes here, but Spring is largely out of the picture.  You keep calling "new".

Comment: This code i written inside try catch block and I'm also printing exceptions(if occurs), But control not going into catch block. The control never returns to program

Comment: I think program goes into wait state

Comment: Try it in a debugger to be sure about what's going on.  Personally, I see too little Spring and too much Oracle.  You shouldn't be calling "new", and you shouldn't need an Oracle data source.

Comment: After debugging my code I got to know that there may be problem in closing clob or in commit, because connection goes into wait state and  waiting for response from DB after firing sql. and it is working perfectly for update query, means if I modify my function and put update query instead of insert query then it will woks

Comment: You have the commit in the stored procedure; try letting the JDBC driver handle the transaction instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Spring Jdbc properly here. 
You should use use MapSqlParameterSource in order to add parameters to. 
In addition, you should use SimpleJdbcCall and use the "widthProcedureName" in order to set the stored procedure to work with.  
At [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) we work with text (which is pgsql equivalent to clob at Oracle) with no problem. 
You can take a look at our code (by git clonning it ) for example - look at ovirt-engine/backend/manager/modules/dal/src/main/java/org/ovirt/engine/core/dao/AsyncTaskDAODbFacadeImpl.java  as an example for usage of Spring JDBC and pgsql text type (which is , as I said the equivalent to clob in Oracle).